# How to Pass the Data from One form to Another Form in Angular2

Tags: angular

I want to pass the data from one form to another. After clicking **Next** button of Form1, Form2 should show the *data entered in Form1*. How to achieve this..Can anyone help me out..Thanks in Advance

**Form1.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="Form1" (ngSubmit)="saveNewCustomer(Form1.value)">
<label>Mobile No.</label>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="MobileNo" placeholder="Mobile No" #MobileNo="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="CustomerForm.MobileNo">
</div>

<label>Name</label>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="Name" placeholder="Name" #Name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="CustomerForm.Name">
</div>

<label>Amount</label>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="Amount" placeholder="Amount" #Amount="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="CustomerForm.Amount">
</div>

<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Next</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Form1.component.ts**

```
export class Form1Component implements OnInit {
public CustomerForm: FormGroup;
public submitted: boolean;
FormValues: FormVM[] = [];
FormValue: FormVM;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private router: Router, private dataService: AppDataService,) { }
ngOnInit() {
    this.CustomerForm = this.fb.group({
        MobileNo: [''],
        Name: [''],
        Amount: ['']
    });
}
saveNewCustomer(customer: FormVM) {      
    this.submitted = true; 
    this.router.navigate(['/Form2']);        
}
```

Above are the Form 1 component code and below is Form 2 component code, which I should get After clicking **Next** button of Form1 
**Form2.component.html**

```
    <h5>Form2</h5>
<form class="cat-form" *ngFor="let list of FormValues">
    <label>Mobile No.</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="MobileNo">
        {{list.MobileNo}}
    </div>

    <label>Name</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="Name">
        {{list.Name}}
    </div>

    <label>Amount</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="Amount">
        {{list.Amount}}
    </div>

</form>
```

**Form2.component.ts**

```
export class Form2Component {
    FormValues: FormVM[] = [];
    FormValue: FormVM;
    constructor(private dataService: AppDataService, private router: Router, private getdata: Form1Component) {
        getdata.FormValues;
    }
    ngOnInit() {

    }
}
```

Comment: if these are separate components, I'd probably use a shared service for storing the form values and inject it into both, so that both form could send to and retrieve data from it

Comment: use this for a reference, https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/dhananjay_kumar/posts/communication-between-components-using-input-in-angular-2

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a custom service for the same which can be shared among various components for example

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ApiService} from './api.service';
import {AuthService} from './auth.service';
//import {ApiService} from './api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  template: `
    <mat-card>
      <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>
          Login New user
        </mat-card-title>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>
        <form>
          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
              <input [(ngModel)]="loginData.email" name="email" matInput placeholder="Email" value=""  type="email">
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <input [(ngModel)]="loginData.password" name="password" matInput placeholder="Password" value="" type="password">
          </mat-form-field>
          <button (click)="post()" mat-raised-button color="primary">Login</button>
       </form>
     </mat-card-content>
   </mat-card>
  `
})
export class LoginComponent {
  constructor(private authService:AuthService){  }
  loginData={
  }
  //  mail:String;
  // password:String;
  //registerData={mail:string,password}

  post(){
    //console.log(this.registerData);
    this.authService.loginUser(this.loginData);//service to pass the login data 
  }
}
```

**register.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from './auth.service';

//import {ApiService} from './api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'register',
  templateUrl:'register.component.html'
})
export class RegisterComponent {
  constructor(private authService:AuthService){  }
  registerData={}

  //  mail:String;
  // password:String;
  //registerData={mail:string,password}

  post(){
    console.log(this.registerData);
    this.authService.registerUser(this.registerData);//authservice function
  }
}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'

@Injectable()
export class AuthService{
  messages=[];
  path='http://localhost:3000/auth';
  TOKEN_KEY='token';
  constructor(private http:HttpClient){}

  // getMessages(){
  //   this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/posts').subscribe(res =>{
  //     //console.log(res);
  //     this.messages=res.json();
  //   })
  // }
  get token(){
    return localStorage.getItem(this.TOKEN_KEY);
  }

  registerUser(registerData){

    this.http.post<any>(this.path+'/register',registerData).subscribe(res =>{
      this.messages=res;
    })
  }
  loginUser(loginData){

    this.http.post<any>(this.path+'/login',loginData).subscribe(res =>{
      console.log(res);
      localStorage.setItem(this.TOKEN_KEY,res.token);
      //this.messages=res.json();
    })
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
    //some imports above//
    import {ApiService} from './api.service';
     @NgModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      RegisterComponent,
      LoginComponent    
    ],
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      MatButtonModule,
      MatCardModule,
      MatToolbarModule,
      MatInputModule,
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      FormsModule,
      MatListModule
    ],
    providers: [AuthService],//other services go inside providers array
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
  export class AppModule { }
```

A simplified plunkr example based on same reference of the code above 
https://plnkr.co/edit/iWTGXE?p=preview

Comment: @ShaileshBhat :i can't add the whole project in plunkr(as its more on personal work) but i have added something very simple 
https://plnkr.co/edit/iWTGXE?p=preview